# Drawing With OPENGL using two GPUs simulatenously

Tags: opengl

I have implemented an application, which I am generating two geometries on two different GPUs using OpenCL kernels. I want to render these geometries on two different GPUs simultaneously and then combine the final images. How can I determine that I want to render the first geometry on the first GPU and second geometry on second GPU, using OpenGL API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the system level APIs for creating OpenGL contexts lack device enumeration and selection, the only more or less reliable way is to create a window within the boundaries of a screen connected to the desired GPU and create the OpenGL context using the HDC of that window (while it is within the boundaries of that screen *and* visible to really force the driver); a 1×1 borderless window suffices.

If you have your monitor(s) connected to only one GPU, well, then you are out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: But this seems so stupid to me that it is not possible to draw using two different devices simultaneously, because we can do that using opencl / cuda kernels easily but it is just too much work and I wanted to find a faster and easier way.

Comment: @mmostajab: Yes, it's totally stupid but not OpenGL's fault. It's the fault of the OS developers who designed the system graphics APIs (WGL, GLX and such). At least in Linux using the open source drivers it's possible to bypass this, but it's a lot of work, and hard to get right and working reliably.

Comment: So, if I have two displays and connect each of them to each GPU, the stuff which I am rendering in a windows in Display 0 will render on GPU 0 and the windows which are shown in Display 1 will render on GPU 1?

And if we move a window from Display 0 to Display 1, we are moving the computations from GPU 0 to GPU 1?

Comment: @mmostajab: Regarding the first part: Essentially yes. Regarding the second part: Well, it's complicated. Keep in mind that there's no strict behavior specified. It's completely up to the drivers how they manage this issue. But we can make a few well founded assumptions: In case of GPUs connected via SLI or CrossFire just transferring the rendered image over the bus may be more bandwidth effective than migrating all the resources involved; or the drivers may decide to migrate over the course of several frames and only switch the GPU when fully done.

Comment: @mmostajab: Multi-GPU management is one of the sore spots of OpenGL context management. And it's actually one among the first, higher priority tasks on the laundry list for the development of the Vulkan API and infrastructure. I for one can't wait for Vulkan to become available. In the meantime: How about using Mantle (Vulkan is likely to be a cleaned up, modified variant of Mantle and): https://medium.com/@Overv/implementing-hello-triangle-in-mantle-4302450fbcd2

Comment: before you said there are some source graphics drivers which we can determine the gpu which the opengl context is going to be created on it. Can you please give me more information on this? Where can I find them and probably some tutorial about them. Because this is something that I reallly need

Comment: @mmostajab: Where did I say that? If you refer to my first comment reply, that it's possible in Linux with the open source drivers: Well, this is so low level that I can hardly recommend going down that route. And AFAIK there's no proper OpenCL support available for this right now, as well. If you want to know how to do this, I recomment you google for "kmscube".

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1, I tried to create two different windows on two displays and connecting each display to one of the gpus, then create one window on each screen and create the opengl context for each window but when I use the weaker gpu, still the buffers and rendering is done on the more powerful gpu. But I implement the same scenario in Ubuntu using GLX, and it worked.
Is there any difference between linux and window in handling such stuff?

Comment: @mmostajab: Countless differences. First and foremost hybrid graphics is much more mature on Windows (higher market pressure). Also in X11 when running multiple GPUs of different making you're getting two independent X *screens* (managed by the same X server). In a vanilla configuration you can't even move windows between X screens; there are extensions like Xinerama which allow to do it, but imposing strong constraints. These days merged framebuffer is the go-to implementation of spanning output to multiple screens and GPUs, but it usually only works with GPUs of the same making.